# publishing the database with the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, publishing

How can I publish the application database along with it?

I'm using *Visual Studio 2008* with *C#* language.
The database has the log-in information needed in order to go in the *MdiParent* and do tasks there. The same database is where employee records would also be saved...
I'm currently developing an employee information system.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option it to use a file based database and distribute it with your application, unless you need the data to be shared between all users of the applications as it changes.

SqlLite and SQL Server CE are both file based.

Answer (score 0):

What is your db  engine? For MySQL, I use the utility mysqldump. You then can use the source command in a scripted installer to deploy your db from the dump file.

With SQLSERVER, I use the Import/Export tool that comes with SQLSERVER to script out the db with any data that I want to have deployed with the database. I then run the script on the db in my installer.

You have several options. The question is, what are you using for an installer? NSIS, Visual Studio Setup Projects? etc... How you answer that will determine the best approach for how to deploy your database.

You can also do as @oded recommends though I have never done this except for with basic ASP.NET sites and the sqlexpress db that come with the VS project. Usually, I find that whether or not it is a good idea to use the file just depends on your complexity.